# helm value files from more than one directoy

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Can we have helm value files from more than one directory?
Below is my observation:

**Works**

```
helm template mychart . --values dir-1/values.yaml
```

**Works**

```
helm template mychart . --values dir-2/values.yaml
```

**Works**

```
helm template mychart . --values dir-1/values-1.yaml --values dir-1/values-2.yaml
```

**Doesn't work**

```
helm template mychart . --values dir-1/values.yaml --values dir-2/values.yaml
```

In the above case helm is only picking the file from one directory only(dir-2).
Is there a way I can use value files from multiple directories?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass multiple values files with `-f` like this:

```
helm template mychart . -f dir-1/values.yaml -f dir-2/values.yaml
```

Note that `dir-2/values.yaml` has precedence over `dir-1/values.yaml` (Helm merges Right to Left). So Helm will merge the 2 files but during key collisions, it'll favor the value from `dir-2/values.yaml`.

Comment: I believe -f is same as --values. It does allow multiple files, but only if they are in the same directory. I have clearly mentioned above what works with this and what not.

Comment: Have you tried? -f allows you to pass multiple files regardless of same/different directories.